# My C++ code seems to stop in the middle of a for loop

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I've been practicing USACO questions and I solved the problem but my code just randomly stops executing in the second for loop.

Code:

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int R = 0;
    int C = 0;
    cin >> R >> C;
    vector<vector<char>> values;
    string temp;
    for (int i = 0; i < R; i++)
    {
        cin >> temp;
        values.push_back(vector<char>());
        for(int j = 0; j < C; j++)
        {
            values[i].push_back(temp[j]);
        }
    }
    int counter = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < R; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < C; j++)
        {
            cout << i << " " << j << endl; //for testing purposes
            if(values[i][j] == '#')
            {
                if(values[i+1][j] != 'a' && values[i-1][j] != 'a' && values[i][j+1] != 'a' && values[i][j-1] != 'a')
                {
                    values[i][j] = 'a';
                    counter += 1;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    cout << counter << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Input:

```
.#....
..#...
..#..#
...##.
.#....
```

Output:

```
0 0
0 1
0 2
0 3
0 4
0 5
1 0
1 1
1 2
1 3
1 4
1 5
2 0
2 1
2 2
2 3
2 4
2 5
3 0
3 1
3 2
3 3
3 4
3 5
4 0
4 1
```

The for loop just stops executing at i = 4 and j = 1, and the program crashes. Please help my identify the problem! Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Starting with C++ without tools like a debugger or, my favourite, an address sanitizer isn't nice. You'll get _so_ much help by just compiling and running your programs with `-g -fsanitize=address,undefined` (if you're using `g++` or `clang++`). - Use that!

Comment: `values[i-1][j]` Change that to: `values.at(i-1).at(j)`.  Now it just won't randomly stop -- what will happen is that it will always stop due to an `std::out_of_range` exception being thrown.  Also, what is `USACO`?  Is it another one of those online coding websites that are not there to teach C++, but instead ask random puzzle questions?

Comment: Also, you tagged `Visual C++` -- I am quite sure that Visual C++ debug runtime would have stopped with an assertion, since the debug version checks boundary conditions for vector.  So are you really using Visual C++, and if so, in debug mode?

Comment: If you happen to use `gcc`/`g++` you may also want to try `-fanalyzer` too. It takes a little longer to compile, but, oh, it's good.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Thanks for the help! USACO is a high school computing competition held monthly from December to February. The problems are similar to code forces questions, except they're generally harder and more time-consuming. I'm taking a prep class, but I guess I should reaffirm my foundation in C++ first. I also had some trouble working the debugger. Sorry, I probably should have taken to a youtube tutorial or something before consulting. Will keep in mind for the future!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When `i` equals zero then `values[i-1][j]` is an out of bounds access on your vector.

When `i` equals `R-1` then `values[i+1][j]` is an out of bounds access on your vector.

Similar errors exist for `j`.